# Javafx Gmapsfx problems with map not loading correctly

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx

I am new here so I have one question. For a little project I have to make a javafx application where I can show the user the route from one location to another one. Like in Gmaps. I searched a bit and found gmapsfx and implemented the Library in my code so the map is loaded, but there is one problem it is watermarked which not really is a bad thing because this is a school project, but whenever I open the app it comes with a warning screen like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhCYT.png)

https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX/issues/149 here it states that when I use a specific constructor It should fix this problem but it still did not help me with it.

Furthermore, I tried to implement the navigation from point a to b like here https://rterp.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/mapping-directions-with-javafx-using-the-gmapsfx-directions-api/
But it does not work for me. I am still an amateur so I don't really know what the problem is my console does not give any errors in eclipse. Maybe I am missing something can someone help me, please?

controllerclass:

```
protected DirectionsService directionsService;
        protected DirectionsPane directionsPane;
        @FXML
        protected GoogleMapView mapView = new GoogleMapView("de-DE", "My-Google-Map-API-Key");;


        @FXML
        private TextField startAirportField;

        @FXML
        private TextField targetField;

        protected StringProperty from = new SimpleStringProperty();
        protected StringProperty to = new SimpleStringProperty();
        protected DirectionsRenderer directionsRenderer = null;

        @FXML
        private void toTextFieldAction() {
            DirectionsRequest request = new DirectionsRequest(from.get(), to.get(), TravelModes.DRIVING);
            directionsRenderer = new DirectionsRenderer(true, mapView.getMap(), directionsPane);
            directionsService.getRoute(request, this, directionsRenderer);
        }

        @Override
        public void directionsReceived(DirectionsResult results, DirectionStatus status) {
        }


        public void initialize() {
            mapView.addMapInializedListener(this);
            to.bindBidirectional(startAirportField.textProperty());
            from.bindBidirectional(targetField.textProperty());
        }
        GoogleMap map ;

        @Override
        public void mapInitialized() {
            MapOptions options = new MapOptions();


            options.center(new LatLong(50.606189, -122.335842))
                    .zoomControl(true)
                    .zoom(12)
                    .overviewMapControl(false)
                    .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.HYBRID);
            map = mapView.createMap(options);
            directionsService = new DirectionsService();
            directionsPane = mapView.getDirec();
        }
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="443.0" prefWidth="711.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.mapsViewController">
   <children>
      <GoogleMapView fx:id="mapView" layoutX="-311.0" layoutY="-244.0" prefWidth="490.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Text fx:id="startAirport" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="20.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Startflughafen" />
            <Text fx:id="targetAirport" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="20.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Zielflughafen" />
            <TextField fx:id="startAirportField" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="25.0" />
            <TextField fx:id="targetField" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="25.0" />
            <Button fx:id="drawLine" layoutX="425.0" layoutY="25.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#toTextFieldAction" text="Suche" />
         </children></GoogleMapView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Log from eclipse:

```
Dez 23, 2019 5:17:03 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.231
Dez 23, 2019 5:17:04 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNUNG: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.231
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView - Alert: Hide directions called
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView - Alert: Hide directions called
```

Answer (score -1):

protected GoogleMapView mapView = new GoogleMapView("de-DE", "My-Google-Map-API-Key");;

expected ";"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it